# Some problems in coding a "guessing random number in C" under some conditions such as using input(), output()

Tags: c, random, input, output

I tried going beyond just guessing random numbers. The conditions were these:

1. use `input()` numbers used from 1 to100 and if inserted numbers that are out of this range, to show a line to re-enter a number
2. use `output()` to show the output(but show the last line```You got it right on your Nth try!" on the main())
3. make the inserted number keep showing on the next line.

Basically, the program should be made to show like this :

```
insert a number : 70
bigger than 0 smaller than 70.
insert a number : 35
bigger than 35 smaller than 70.
insert a number : 55
bigger than 55 smaller than 70.
insert a number : 60
bigger than 55 smaller than 60.
insert a number : 57
You got it right on your 5th try!
```

I've been working on this already for 6 hours now...(since I'm a beginner)... and thankfully I've been able to manage to get the basic structure so that the program would at least be able to show whether the number is bigger than the inserted number of smaller than the inserted number.

The problem is, I am unable to get the numbers to be keep showing on the line. For example, I can't the inserted number `70` keep showing on `smaller than 70`.

Also, I am unable to find out how to get the number of how many tries have been made. I first tried to put it in the input() as `count = 0 ... count++;` but failed in the output. Then I tried to put in in the output(), but the output wouldn't return the `count` so I failed again.

I hope to get advice on this problem.

The following is the code that I wrote that has no errors, but problems in that it doesn't match the conditions of the final outcome.
(By the way, I'm currently using Visual Studio 2017 which is why there is a line of `#pragma warning (disable : 4996)`, and `myflush` instead of `fflush`.)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma warning (disable : 4996)

int input();
int random(int);
void myflush();
void output(int, int);

int main()
{
    int num;
    int i;
    int ran;

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    i = 0;
    while (i < 1) {
        ran = 1 + random(101);  
        ++i;
    }

    num = input();
    output(ran, num);

    printf("You got it right on your    th try!");a

    return 0;
}

int input()
{
    int num;
    printf("insert a number : ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    while (num < 1 || num > 100 || getchar() != '\n') {
        myflush();
        printf("insert a number : ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
    }
    return num;
}


int random(int n)
{
    int res;
    res = rand() % n;
    return res;
}

void myflush()
{
    while (getchar() != '\n') {
        ;
    }
    return;
}


void output(int ran, int num) {
    while (1) {
        if (num != ran){
            if (num < ran) {
            printf("bigger than %d \n", num);  // 
            }
            else if (num > ran) {
                printf("smaller than %d.\n", num);
            }
            printf("insert a number : ");
            scanf("%d", &num);
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: This line in `main` must be a typo? `printf("You got it right on your    th try!");a` .  It needs a format specifier, and a value.  eg: `printf("You got it right on your   %d th try!", count);` See answer for more details.

Comment: oh I actually excluded that part because I wasn't sure if I had to put the ```%d``` for sure or not since it didn't work even if I put it in anyway.

Comment: Yes, its needed if you want to show a count.  Before passing back a value from the `output` function, there was nothing you could have printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I am unable to find out how to get the number of how many tries have been made.*

Change the `output` function from `void` to `int` so it can return a value for count, and note comments for other changes:

```
int output(int ran, int num) {//changed from void to int
    int count = 0;//create a variable to track tries
    while (1) {
        if (num != ran){
            count++;//increment tries here and...
            if (num < ran) {
                printf("bigger than %d \n", num);  // 
            }
            else if (num > ran) {
                printf("smaller than %d.\n", num);
            }
            printf("insert a number : ");
            scanf("%d", &num);
        }
        else {
            count++;//... here
            break;
        }
    }
    return count;//return value for accumulated tries
}
```

Then in `main`:

```
//declare count
int count = 0;
...
count = output(ran, num);
printf("You got it right on your %dth try!", count);
```

With these modifications, your code ran as you described above.
(However, `th` doesn't work so well though for the 1st, 2nd or 3rd tries)

Comment: Thank you very much. What you have showed me is actually how the answer to getting the number of tries being made. I think you meant you were unable to get how to keep the numbers showing on the outcome like ```insert : 70 ... bigger than 35 smaller than 70```.

Comment: @Learner_15 - Yes, if that is what is desired, a value for the two conditions can be kept in the `output` function, for example by using two variables:  `int larger = 0; int smaller = 0`, then update these as they are changed and modify the output statement.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to get the code done!

Comment: I was just about to post the additional modifications.  I am glad you did it yourself!

Answer (score 2):

There are many problem and possible simplifications in this code.

- use `fgets` to read a line then `scanf` the line content. This avoids the need of `myflush` which doesn’t work properly.
- the function `random` is not needed since picking a random number is a simple expression.
- if the range of the random number is [1,100], you should use `1+rand()%100`.
- there is no real need for the function `output` since it’s the core of the main program. The `input` function is however good to keep to encapsulate input.
- you should test the return value of `scanf` because the input may not always contain a number.

Here is a simplified code that provides the desired output.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma warning (disable : 4996)

int input() {
    char line[100];
    int num, nVal;
    printf("insert a number : ");
    fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);    
    nVal = sscanf(line, "%d", &num);
    while (nVal != 1 || num < 1 || num > 100) {
        printf("insert a number : ");
        fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);    
        nVal = sscanf(line, "%d", &num);
    }
    return num;
}

int main()
{
    int cnt = 0, lowerLimit = 0, upperLimit = 101;

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    // pick a random number in the range [1,100]
    int ran = 1 + rand()%100;

    while(1) {
        cnt++;
        int num = input();
        if (num == ran)
            break;
        if (num > lowerLimit && num < upperLimit) {
            if (num < ran)
                lowerLimit = num;
            else
                upperLimit = num;           
        }
        printf("bigger than %d and smaller than %d\n", lowerLimit, upperLimit);
    }
    printf("You got it right on your %dth try!\n", cnt);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Although I had the intention to include an ```output```, the code you gave me gave me a clearer path, and I was able to make an ```output``` on my own, though yes, I do agree that this is so much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the program to always display the highest entered number that is lower than the random number ("bigger than") and the lowest entered number that is higher then the random number ("smaller than"), then your program must remember these two numbers so it can update and print them as necessary.

In the function `main`, you could declare the following two ints:

`int bigger_than, smaller_than;`

These variables must go into the function `main`, because these numbers must be remembered for the entire duration of the program. The function `main` is the only function which runs for the entire program, all other functions only run for a short time. An alternative would be to declare these two variables as global. However, that is considered bad programming style.

These variables will of course have to be updated when the user enters a new number.

These two ints would have to be passed to the function `output` every time it is called, increasing the number of parameters of this function from 2 to 4.

If you want a counter to count the number of numbers entered, you will also have to remember this value in the function main (or as a global variable) and pass it to the function `output`. This will increase the number of parameters for the function to 5.

If you don't want to pass so many parameters to output, you could merge the contents of the functions `output` and `input` into the function `main`.

However, either way, you will have to move most of the "smaller than" and "bigger than" logic from the function `output` into the function `main`, because that logic is required for changing the new "bigger_than" and "smaller_than" int variables which belong to the function main. The function `output` should only contain the actual printing logic.

Although it is technically possible to change these two variables that belong to the function `main` from inside the function `output`, I don't recommend it, because that would get messy. It would require you to pass several pointers to the function `output`, which would allow that function to change the variables that belong to the function `main`.

I have now written my own solution and I found that it is much easier to write by merging the function `output` into `main`. I also merged all the other functions into `main`, but that wasn't as important as merging the function `output`.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma warning (disable : 4996)

int main()
{
    const char *ordinals[4] = { "st", "nd", "rd", "th" };
    int num_tries = 0;
    int bigger_than = 0, smaller_than = 101;
    int input_num;
    int random_num;

    srand( (unsigned int)time( NULL ) );
    random_num = 1 + rand() % 101;

    for (;;) //infinite loop, equivalent to while(1)
    {
        printf( "Bigger than: %d, Smaller than: %d\n", bigger_than, smaller_than );

        printf( "enter a number: " );
        scanf( "%d", &input_num );
        printf( "You entered: %d\n", input_num );

        num_tries++;

        if ( input_num == random_num ) break;

        if ( input_num < random_num )
        {
            if ( bigger_than < input_num )
            {
                bigger_than = input_num;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ( smaller_than > input_num )
            {
                smaller_than = input_num;
            }
        }
    }

    printf( "You got it right on your %d%s try!", num_tries, ordinals[num_tries<3?num_tries:3] );

    return 0;
}
```

Also, I made sure that the program would print "1st", "2nd" and "3rd", whereas all the other solutions simply print "1th", "2th", "3th". I used the c++ conditional operator for this.

Comment: hmm.. I kind of get the direction, but then again, as  a beginner, it is quite difficult to understand just by words.. still, thank you for the idea.. I think I will carefully try and develop the code from what you suggested.

Comment: It would have been easier for me to simply provide you with the solution, instead of explaining to you in such detail how to solve it yourself. However, I believe you will learn a lot more if you accomplish it yourself. Still, since you already spent 6 hours on the program, I would be prepared to provide you with the solution, if you wish.

Comment: It's okay now! Thank you very much for your direction. Thanks to the help from others I was able to complete it. And after completing it, I now think I kind of get what you were getting at :)

Comment: @Learner_15: I have updated my answer to include my solution. It turned out that merging the `output` function into `main` made things a lot easier.

Comment: @Learner_15: I have now updated my code once more. I went back to the previous wording of "bigger than" and "smaller than". I noticed that I had wrongly assumed that you had meant "at least" instead of "bigger than". However, I have now noticed that my assumption was incorrect. Your original wording was appropriate. Therefore, there was no reason for me to change the wording. For this reason, I have now changed my code to reflect the original meaning of the wording.

Comment: Thank you for keep on updating trying to give me the best! :D ..and if it's not much of a bother, I would like to ask for one more help..? I actually had to go and ask it again as an official question, but I had problem in the output where the inserting number would go out of range and yet be printed out. If you have the time , I would appreciate it if you would be able to give me some advice on that one as well :).. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59632351/how-do-i-solve-this-problem-with-the-output-being-unable-to-get-the-statement-of)

Comment: @Learner_15: My code already has a solution to the problem you are having. I only update the integers `bigger_than` and `smaller_than` if the numbers are in the appropriate range. However, I will look for the best fix for your code and will write a reply in your other question thread.

Comment: thank you very much. i already tried out your answer and found out it works completely. yet, i wanted to know the problem with my own code cos even though it is a bit of a mess, i think that it should work.. sorry to keep bothering you. I really appreciate the help and advice!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205541/discussion-between-andreas-wenzel-and-learner-15).